# apply function to every combination of rows R

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

say i have a 1802 by 2 matrix of coordinates (longitude/latitude) `coord` each row thus representing a point in space.

```
   [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -90.0   -5
[2,] -87.5   -5
[3,] -85.0   -5
[4,] -82.5   -5
[5,] -80.0   -5
[6,] -77.5   -5
```

I use the `geosphere` package  `distGeo` function that computes de geodesic distance between two points p1 and p2 i.e

```
distGeo(coord[1,],coord[2,])
```

I would like to build a symmetric metric matrix (thus 1802*2,1802*2) of distance between every points in `coord`

trying loops as

```
for (i in 1:nrow(coord)){ 
 for (j in 1:nrow(coord)){
  distGeo(coord[i,],coord[j,])
 }
 }
```

takes forever (even using doMPI and chunking) and as far as i know `outer` can only work with lenght 1 arguments.

Any idea?

Comment: You may need the `?combn` i.e. `combn(seq_len(nrow(coord)), 2, FUN= function(x) distGeo(coord[x[1],], coord[x[2],]))`

Comment: thank you. But it doesn't compare one element with itself (i.e where distance will be zero, the diagonal of the matrix) and it doesn't seem to use combinations in both ways (i.e 1-2 and 2-1). Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: In that case use `expand.grid` or `outer`

Comment: As i've said, outer doesn't seem to accept length 2 (longitude and latitude) as arguments.

Comment: I guess you can use that in `list`, (not tested)

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work neither. The error is not from `outer` but from `distGeo`, it waits for vector of length 2 and doing `outer(coord,coord,"%dist_geo%")` doesn't bring coord in the desired format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the solution in R but resorted to a C++ loop solution via Rcpp that took only 0.3 sec to run.

Basic steps:

1/ transform the lat/lon coordinates into n-vectors (each point is a 3d vector)

2/ create a function to calculate the crossproduct, dotproduct and atan2 of the two in C++ (following the algorithm depicted [here](http://johnblackburne.blogspot.fr/2012/05/angle-between-two-3d-vectors.html)) for each point_i,j. Input is a NumericMatrix with each point n-vector. Result is a NumericMatrix that contains angles between each point (in radians).

3/With Rcpp, you simply call the function from R and voila!